# Is there a standard reference for: taking projective covers of simple modules commutes with finite Galois field extensions?

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, projective-modules, associative-algebras

Let $\Lambda$ be an Artin algebra over a finite field $k$. Is there a standard reference for the fact that taking projective covers of simple $\Lambda$-modules commutes with finite Galois field extensions?

(a reference for the case that $\Lambda$ is finite-dimensional and the simple $\Lambda$-modules are finitely generated would also be interesting)